# Provide Stickers/Gifs for Google Keyboard?

Tags: android, ios, ime

I got a strange feature request on my desk. Marketing people see this stickers all over the messengers and want to have their "own company sticker".

So far so "good". With iOS you can provide Custom Stickers for the App Store. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/stickers/)

With Android we now have Gifs and stuff within the [GBoard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en).
Is it possible to provide Stickers to the GBoard? Maybe via a `ContentProvider`?

The only thing I found so far is the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html) on how it's possible to write an IME which lets you use the GBoard Gifs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Android Developers Blog Post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/create-stickers-for-gboard-on-google.html). To get your stickers featured in the Play Store in the Sticker Collection, you must make a special request by filling out [a special form.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfnJdac94B4a68jltJlkDyDdVMsSthDYQUH8p1rkbEGChnBDg/viewform)

Also see this [app-indexing sample code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/app-indexing), which contains a specialized content provider for stickers, named "StickerProvider."

But, also note that there is some confusion and [an open SO question about how to make GBoard find stickers by keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050682/gboard-sticker-search-doesnt-return-result)